# Java: How do I Put a Canvas in a Canvas?

Tags: java, canvas

Lets say I Have a `Canvas`, like the one below -

```
Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
canvas1.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
panel.add(canvas1);
```

Now I have `canvas1`. Lets say I want to make another `Canvas`, Like the one below -

```
Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
canvas2.setBounds(0,0,50,50);
panel.add(canvas2);
```

As you can see, I have added `canvas2` inside `canvas1`, But when I try to use `canvas2`, it doesn't work because it's inside `canvas1`. Is There anyway to make `canvas1` and `canvas2` work at the Same time without changing any of my code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And use all Swing components.

Answer (score 0):

We need allot more detail from you if you want help. What doesn't work? Painting? Location?

The way you setup your canvases looks fine, are you overriding paint correctly like this:

`java.awt.Canvas canvas2 = new CanvasTest();`

```
public class CanvasTest extends Canvas
{
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        //paint to your canvas here
        g.drawRect(5,5, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
You have not put canvas2 inside canvas1, you have added them both to "panel": **`panel`**`.add(canvas1);`, **`panel`**`.add(canvas2);`
please be careful how you word your questions